# download a certificate from a ldap server in java

Tags: ldap, certificate

Can someone explain to me whether following code is correct to download a certificate ties to a specific person in java? I am getting an exception as "unknown protocol: ldaps".

```
public void downloadCert() {
    String urlStr="ldaps://aServerSomeWhere:636/cn=doe%20john,ou=personnel,o=comany123,c=us?caCertificate;binary";
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(is);
        System.out.println("getVersion: " + cert.getVersion());
     } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

Comment: please refer to :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't correct. There is no handler for the LDAPS: protocol in the URL/URLConnection system.

You can use JNDI to get the caCertificate attribute of that user, via DirContext.getAttributes().